# show <rich:tab> contents while navigating only if action Performed is YES

Tags: jsf-2, tabs, richfaces, actionlistener

I am using RF3.3 and JSF(2.0) wiht JSPs in the project.

My page contains 4 tabs inside a tab panel.
When page is first loaded, the TAB1 is automatically selected which is ok.
Now before user navigate from one tab to another tab I need to show him a pop up panel asking his confirmation to move from one tab to another. So when User present on TAB 1 clicks on TAB2 I want a pop up panel asking user whether he is sure to navigate to TAB2.

The problem is: Once I click tab 2 the action listener present with `<rich:tab>` is fired and tab2  is rendered and only then pop up panel comes.

Is there any way to open pop up panel once user click on TAB 2 and only if he clicks YES in pop up panel the contents of TAB 2 is shown.

I cannot use disabled attribute since using that I won't be able to click on TAB 2 and my pop up panel won't open.

```
<rich:tabPanel id="tab" switchType="ajax" headerSpacing="10px"style="overflow:auto"> 

<rich:tab binding="#{Bean.firsttab}" id="tabOne" style="overflow:auto" styleClass="richTab" label="TAB ONE" actionListener="#{Bean.refresh}" switchType="ajax">

<rich:tab binding="#{Bean.secondtab}" id="tabTwo" style="overflow:auto" styleClass="richTab" label="TABTWO" actionListener="#{Bean.refresh}" switchType="ajax">

</rich:tabPanel>
```

I preferably don't want to use Javascript to achieve the same. How can I achieve this in JSF?

Comment: This can be achieved by JavaScript only, using the `ontabenter` javascript function of your tabTwo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the same by binding the tab with the backing bean and using the property of the tab to render and rerender the tab based on some conditions...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using `onlabelclick` inside `<rich:tab`. Call a JS method inside this and return a boolean to proceed to the action or not. Hope this works. If it worked kindly post your code snippet in this.

Comment: I don't want to use javascript as I have already mentioned that in my post....Howeve I achieved the same by binding the tab and using few of the tab properties.